# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS not found?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have set my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to ~/mailcreds.json like so

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="~/mailcreds.json"
```

However, any time I run my DialogFlow project that entails requesting them I get this

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-04-04T19:50:12.350+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Error reading credential file from environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, value '~/mailcreds.json': File does not exist."}
```

I am mystified by this!  The file is in my home directory!

Answer (score 4):

When you do something like `cat ~/mailcreds.json`, the tilde `~` is processed by the shell and converted to the value in the environment variable `$HOME`. Not all runtime environments handle this correctly, however.

Your best bet is to change this to something like

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="$HOME/mailcreds.json"
```

this works because the shell interprets `$HOME` immediately, so `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` would be set to the full path to the file.

Even better, however, would be to actually just set the full path to the file directly.

Make sure you are also running your project using an account that is permitted to access the file. If you're running the project as yourself (because you're developing/testing it), then you should be ok for the moment, but this is bad practice for something in produciton.

Comment: This environment variable should be set to the full pathname and not rely upon environment variables for the same reason you do not want to use `~/mailcreds.json`. Also, credentials should not be stored relative to home directories as the service might not have permission to access files under $HOME and $HOME will have a different path for each user / service.

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify a little, but in this case, you wouldn't have the same problem using $HOME because the shell would evaluate that when the export is called, unlike ~. Your other points are certainly valid for a production service, but when developing, it may still be useful to do it this way.

Comment: $HOME is a user environment variable. Do NOT use that when specifying paths.